# TimerHandler duplicating and cannot be unregistered in andengine

Tags: android, timer, andengine

I need some help with a strange problem I am having involving TimerHandlers. For some reason when I call unregisterUpdateHandler on my set of timers they don't get removed on the first pass. This problem has been driving me nuts since it makes absolutely no sense to me. I only add the timers once and unregistered them when restarting my level. If I don't register a new set of timers the old ones persist as if I never unregistered them and they stay until I restart the level again then they're finally gone. Has anyone else ever encountered this problem?

These are all part of the same class

```
@Override
public void createScene() {

    createBackground();
    createHUD();
    createPhysics();

    if(!firstTry)
    {
        createSprites();
        firstTry = true;

    }
    loadLevel(1);
    createGameOverText();
    loadData();
    //levelCompleteWindow = new LevelCompleteWindow(vbom);

    setOnSceneTouchListener(this);

}

public void createSprites()
{
    updater =  new TimerHandler(1f, new ITimerCallback() 
    {
        public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) 
        {

            updateTime();
            /*if(timeRemaining <=0)
            {
                player.onDie();
            }*/
            pTimerHandler.reset();
        }
    });
    itemMaker = new TimerHandler(5f, new ITimerCallback() 
    {
        public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) 
        {
            createItem();
            pTimerHandler.reset();
        }
    });
    enemyMaker = new TimerHandler(2.5f, new ITimerCallback() 
    {
        public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) 
        {
            createEnemy();
            pTimerHandler.reset();
        }
    });

    player = new Player(SCREEN_WIDTH/10,SCREEN_HEIGHT-ResourceManager.getInstance().player_region.getHeight(), vbom, camera, physicsWorld)
    {

        @Override
        public void onDie() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!gameOverDisplayed)
            {
                displayGameOverText();
                saveData();
                createMenuChildScene();
                //Log.d("TEST","CALLED");
                physicsWorld.unregisterPhysicsConnector(this.fall);
                //unregisterUpdateHandler(updater);
                //unregisterUpdateHandler(itemMaker);
                //unregisterUpdateHandler(enemyMaker);
                //unregisterUpdateHandler(increase);
            }
        }

    };
    this.registerUpdateHandler(updater);
    this.registerUpdateHandler(itemMaker);
    this.registerUpdateHandler(enemyMaker);
    //this.registerUpdateHandler(increase);
}
```

This is called when the player dies to restart the scene without reloading the class

```
private void cleanUp()
{
    this.detachChildren();
    menuChildScene.back();

    timeRemaining = 30;
    totalTime = 0;
    isRunning=false;
    gameOverDisplayed = false;
    //Log.d("TEST","PLayer Y:"+ player.getY());
    //player.setY(SCREEN_HEIGHT-ResourceManager.getInstance().player_region.getHeight());
    //player.
    //updater.reset();
    //itemMaker.reset();
    //enemyMaker.reset();
    //increase.reset();
    this.unregisterUpdateHandler(updater);
    this.unregisterUpdateHandler(itemMaker);
    this.unregisterUpdateHandler(enemyMaker);
    //this.unregisterUpdateHandler(increase);
    Log.d("TEST","Handlers Unregistered");
    //physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(player.fall);
    player = new Player(SCREEN_WIDTH/10,SCREEN_HEIGHT-ResourceManager.getInstance().player_region.getHeight(), vbom, camera, physicsWorld)
    {

        @Override
        public void onDie() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!gameOverDisplayed)
            {
                displayGameOverText();
                saveData();
                createMenuChildScene();
                //Log.d("TEST","CALLED");
                physicsWorld.unregisterPhysicsConnector(this.fall);
                //unregisterUpdateHandler(updater);
                //unregisterUpdateHandler(itemMaker);
                //unregisterUpdateHandler(enemyMaker);
                //unregisterUpdateHandler(increase);
            }
        }

    };
    //this.unregisterUpdateHandlers(pUpdateHandlerMatcher);
}
```

I'll add more code if needed but these are the only instances where TimerHandlers are referenced. As you can see, I tried to unregister the timers multiple times before but the results were the same with the timers not being removed until the second pass/death

EDIT: Here is the whole class (Kinda messy and a bit hard to read)
https://gist.github.com/powerbot99/6030edb3e4c1e84a6200

Comment: Well the issue sure doesn't appear to be here. Can you post the whole class maybe? (put it up no Gist https://gist.github.com/ with a link?)

Comment: Added as requested. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't emulate what you're doing, this is going to be a guess, and a fairly unsubstantiated one. 
You code looks like it should work.

BUT

In all of the examples for TimerHandlers being saved to a variable, they are assigned within the registerUpdateHandler command.

```
registerUpdateHandler(spriteTimerHandler = new TimerHandler(mEffectSpawnDelay,true,new ITimerCallback()
        {                      
            @Override
            public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler)
            {

                //Random Position Generator
                final float xPos = MathUtils.random(30.0f, (CAMERA_WIDTH - 30.0f));
                        final float yPos = MathUtils.random(30.0f, (CAMERA_HEIGHT - 30.0f));

                        createSprite(xPos, yPos);
            }
        }));
```

We both know this should not make a difference. But for fun and giggles, try that and see. Like so:

```
this.registerUpdateHandler(updater =  new TimerHandler(1f, new ITimerCallback() 
{
    public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) 
    {

        updateTime();
        /*if(timeRemaining <=0)
        {
            player.onDie();
        }*/
        pTimerHandler.reset();
    }
}));
this.registerUpdateHandler( itemMaker = new TimerHandler(5f, new ITimerCallback() 
{
    public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) 
    {
        createItem();
        pTimerHandler.reset();
    }
});

this.registerUpdateHandler(    enemyMaker = new TimerHandler(2.5f, new ITimerCallback() 
{
    public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) 
    {
        createEnemy();
        pTimerHandler.reset();
    }
})));
```

I'm not super optimistic, but let me know.

Comment: No change. There still is a mysterious second set of timers and still requires a second death until they are all properly removed.